# Измение цвета подсветки синтаксиса в Atom

Tags: python, atom

Как изменить цвет подсветки синтаксиса Python в редакторе Atom?
Я новичок в программировании, по этому извиняюсь за возможно примитивный вопрос.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы изменить цвет синтаксиса, тебе нужно **поменять тему оформления** в Atom.

Для этого заходишь в **настройки**, во вкладку **Install**, далее в поиске вводишь название темы(их список можешь найти [здесь](https://atom.io/themes)). И далее **устанавливаешь** её. После этого в настройках во вкладке **Themes** находишь **Syntax Theme**  в правой стороне окна, и **меняешь** тему оформления на скачанную.

Надеюсь мой ответ помог вам!

Comment: А возможно ли настраивать цвета подсветки непосредственно в теме?